# How read Linux or Mac created file in Windows via C FILE*?

Tags: c++, c, file, newline

As all we know in windows EOL is CRLF and in linux LF and CR in Mac. ([more_info](http://mc-computing.com/languages/CR_LF.htm))

I want to write a program which reads as linux and Mac as well Win files line by line in Windows. To open file I would use fopen in "rt" mode, but I don't know how read lines. fgets reads until CRLF and LF under Windows but I want it to work for EOL=CR files also.

So what is the solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Linux uses LF not CR. MacOS9 used plain CR.

Comment: Yes you are right PiotrLegnica http://mc-computing.com/languages/CR_LF.htm this is whole list.

Comment: @Mihran: MacOSX uses LF.

Comment: I can't believe people still think windows requires CRLF.  Even recent versions of notepad accept LF only files!  Why do people still write software that emits non-standard CRLF or CR line endings?

Comment: Maybe you are right @André but I want my program to work with files which are created and edited by different editors and in different OS.

Comment: @Mihran: yeah, I know.  That's why I posted it as a comment, and not an answer :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I couldn't find nothing good for me and decided to write my own `my_fgets` function which uses `fgetc` in body.

Answer (score 2):

To open in "t" mode, the file must conform to the platform you are running on. Otherwise you just have to open in binary mode, and sort the difference out yourself.

The C library helps you write a program that works roughly the same on different platforms, but does not support "cross reading" the files.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you open the file in rt mode  (read - text), you should be fine. fgets() will return one line, and will handle the subtle differences between platforms. When writing to a file, use '\n' as the EOL, and you will get the correct line endings for your platform. This is the reason for opening the file in text mode. If you use binary mode, you will have to handle all the different line endings in your software.

Comment: I'm getting file via my client program in windows from Linux server. That's why in most cases files from which I'll read have linux format EOL.

Comment: @Mihran: it doesn't matter, the difference will be handled for you by the streams, so don't worry about it... unless you want to write files with Linux line endings from Windows :)

Comment: I have try. It doesn't work:( LF and CRLF works in Windows, but CR not. Haven't try this in Mac and Linux, but sure that there everything will be ok.

Comment: Most C libraries do *not* implement what is usually called "universal newline mode" -- if the file isn't in the platform's convention, no line breaks for you!